# Use Flask-Security to change password in code

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I want to create a page to edit some user data, including the password.  How can I change the password in my own view with Flask-Security?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`hash_password`](https://flask-security.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/api.html?highlight=hash_password#flask_security.utils.hash_password) to hash the password with Flask-Security.

```
from flask_security.utils import hash_password
user.password = hash_password('Stack Overflow')
```

Unless you have a good reason not to, you should use the built-in change password [view and form](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html).  Flask-Security offers the ability to customize both.  Leaving the change password form in its own page is a common pattern.